# How to clean populate_sdk in yocto

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, yocto

We can clean a particular recipe by using *-c* option, for example:

```
bitbake -c cleanall core-image-sato
```

But when we are trying to build "SDK", we run the following command:

```
bitbake -c populate_sdk core-image-sato
```

How to clean the output generated by the above command.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to clean SDK's AFAIK. You can remove the SDK directory `tmp/deploy/sdk` and re-compile it again using `--force` option.

Comment: In my system tmp/deploy/sdk contains only a large install script. Where are the generated sdk files actually?

Comment: The .sh file is the installer for your SDK

Comment: Maybe workaround by cleaning the image?
`bitbake core-image-sato -c cleansstate` then
`bitbake core-image-sato -c populate_sdk`
On my machine this forces the rebuild of the SDK *.sh file

Comment: I wouldn't recommend to `cleansstate` the image itself. Isn't it too much? The SDK itself is cleanable by removing the `/tmp/deploy/sdk` directory (as mentioned by @MubinIcyer).
The packages that are composing the SDK itself are somewhere else, though. Have a look into the `/tmp/work` and you should find useful things over there.

Answer (score 0):

The SDKs contain packages determined by the meta-environment and meta-environment-extsdk recipes. These are appended with the BSP/machine name on the fly, but they can be called if you know the BSP/machine name:

You can try

`bitbake meta-environment-<machine> -c cleanall` for the SDK

`bitbake meta-environment-extsdk-<machine> -c cleanall` for the eSDK

Now when you build the SDK/eSDK again it should fully rebuild.